# Possible to remap the Fn+C/V to Ctrl+C/V key combinations on a Thinkpad?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, remapping, fn-key

I know remapping the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key alone seems like its impossible, but what about the actual combination?

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to be remapped to the<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Doable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swapping the Fn and Ctrl Keys on a Lenovo ThinkPad Keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/990561/swapping-the-fn-and-ctrl-keys-on-a-lenovo-thinkpad-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Not only does <kbd>Fn</kbd> usually not generate a usable keycode, but it will also not generate a usable keycode unless used with specific keys, as determined by the hardware. It does not generally act as a modifier. You can try to use `xmodmap` to remap its raw scancode to an actual modifier, but this will not work on all laptops.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> is a key that doesn't generate a scancode, thus there's no way to remap it, except on some hardware that allows generating a scancode for it like Mac.

If you only want to swap <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then look for the function in BIOS setup, most laptops that have <kbd>Fn</kbd> on the left of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> have this option