# Swapping the Fn and Ctrl Keys on a Lenovo ThinkPad Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, fn-key, button-remapping

I have this [keyboard](http://search.ncix.com/products/?sku=SY4976453), and I'm trying to remap <kbd>Fn</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Fn</kbd>, if at all possible.

I read in some links that the scan code of <kbd>Fn</kbd> is only detectable by the Lenovo driver and not Windows. It's really annoying that they have it setup like that.

Is there any way to remap these keys? (Possibly via a hook to the driver or Autohotkey or something)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/476987/how-can-i-swap-ctrl-and-fn-keys-on-a-corporate-computer Perhaps try AutoHotkey

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swapping Function (Fn) and Control (Ctrl) Keys on Lenovo ThinkPad W500](https://superuser.com/questions/49412/swapping-function-fn-and-control-ctrl-keys-on-lenovo-thinkpad-w500)

Answer (score 2):

Lenovo laptops (2008 models and newer) have a setting in the BIOS to switch these two keys.

There is no other way to do it except in the BIOS, because the Fn key is intercepted in hardware (*only* in combination with other keys), and never shows up in the operating system.

If you are not using the keyboard with a Lenovo branded system, you may not be able to do it at all.

Comment: There are some indications online that you can hook the keyboard up to a Thinkpad, change the BIOS setting, then move the keyboard to a different computer and it will remember what it was set to, but they are anecdotal at best, and I have not seen them work, so I'm not including them as part of my answer.

Comment: 2008 and newer models include all machines with models starting with a letter followed by three numbers, e.g. T500, T400, W500, X200 and W700. Older models, such as those with model codes that start with a letter followed by only two numbers, do not have this setting in the BIOS.

Comment: @BramMooij I moved the specific list of models to a comment so that it is easier to read the answer.